# Add a class to a formField in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In prestashop 1.7 the FormField class is used to define, well, the form fields of the registration and address forms like this :

```
$format['firstname'] = (new FormField)
        ->setName('firstname')
        ->setLabel(
            $this->translator->trans(
                'First name',
                [],
                'Shop.Forms.Labels'
            )
        )
        ->setRequired(true);
```

Now with the old helper form it was possible to set a class on a form field so that it would be possible to style the form in CSS.

The FormField class doesn't seem to have any attribute relating to this

```
private $name               = '';
private $type               = 'text';
private $required           = false;
private $label              = '';
private $value              = null;
private $availableValues    = [];
private $maxLength          = null;
private $errors             = [];
private $constraints        = [];
```

The fieldFormatter implements the render method that is defined in the core.

To get to my question, is it possible to add an attribute to the FormField without having to modify the core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the solution lied in the additional values of the formField and the form-fields.tpl

```
->addAvailableValue('class', 'left')
```

And the in the form-fields.tpl

```
{block name='form_field_item_other'}
<label {if $field.required and isset($field.availableValues.class)}
  class="required {$field.availableValues.class}"
{elseif $field.required} class="required"{/if} >
  <span>{$field.label}</span>
  <input name="{$field.name}" type="{$field.type}" value="{$field.value}" {if $field.required}required{/if}>
</label>
{/block}
```

This way you can also add form groups, ids and other interesting stuff.